# Async await `this` is not defined with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a problem using async await in react, this is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "stage-2",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

I don't have problem using async await to call api but can't setState because the `this` is not defined

```
class App extends Component {

  testAsync = async () => {
    const { body } = await requestOuter('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users')
    console.log(body) //working, body is bunch of array of object
    this.setState({body}) //this is not defined error?
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.testAsync()}>test async</button>
      {(this.state.body || []).map(o => o.login)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of `transform-async-to-generator` are you using: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2765

Comment: Your defining the testAsync like a var,.. you want it to be a method of the  class, just do .. `async testAsync() {`  In fact with Babel I get an error with this what you have done.

Comment: Are you able to post the output after a babel compile of this snippet?

Comment: @Keith what's wrong with that? a function suppose can be to assign to a var?

Comment: @DavinTryon babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1"

Comment: @SharonChai `what's wrong with that?` your defining a class, `Component {` the code after this is not the body of any function, not even the constructor.  So it's basically a syntax error.  Why not try what I suggested?..  Simply,  `async testAsync() {` , this is how you bind a method to a class, no assignment needed.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is reference to current object in execution, inside promise `this` is not same as application scope.

try:

```
<button onClick={() => {var self=this; this.testAsync(self);}}>test async</button>
```

.

```
testAsync = async (self) => {
    const { body } = await requestOuter('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users')
    console.log(body) //working, body is bunch of array of object
    self.setState({body}) ;
  }
```

You have to try variation of this of this approach. One variation should work as per scope of application.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
async testAsync() {
    const { body } = await requestOuter('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users')
    console.log(body) //working, body is bunch of array of object
    this.setState({body}) //this is not defined error?
  }
```

and I have to use arrow function in the jsx

Update: this is caused by react-hot-loader, wow didn't expect that!
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/391